# Clicking the button concurrently using replaceWith without refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure it out how can I click my button concurrently without refresh my browser. I noticed that if I clicked one of the buttons it's working and replacing it's new value using `.replaceWith` but when I click another button it doesn't give me a another value.

**Code:**

```
<body>
<input type = "button" id = "bt1" value = "See my Full Name :)">
<input type = "button" id = "bt2" value = "See my Nickname :)">

<div>
    <div class = "name">See my name</div>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#bt1").click
        (
            function ()
            {
                $("div.name").replaceWith("<div>John Francis</div>");
                alert("Your full name is John Francis");
            }
        );

        $("#bt2").click
        (
            function ()
            {
                $("div.name").replaceWith("<div>Francis</div>");
                alert("Your nickname is Francis");
            }
        );
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding the classname `.name` to the newly inserted DIV that you replace, so the next time you click, there is no element with the class `.name`.

It would be a lot easier to just update the text

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bt1").click(function() {
        $(".name").text("John Francis");
        alert("Your full name is John Francis");
    });

    $("#bt2").click(function() {
        $(".name").text("Francis");
        alert("Your nickname is Francis");
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hurmqrxL/)

If for some reason you have to use replaceWith *(which you don't)*, just add the class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bt1").click(function() {
        $(".name").replaceWith("<div class='name'>John Francis</div>");
        alert("Your full name is John Francis");
    });

    $("#bt2").click(function() {
        $(".name").replaceWith("<div class='name'>Francis</div>");
        alert("Your nickname is Francis");
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hurmqrxL/1/)

Comment: Why should I use `.text` instead of `.replaceWith` is there a way using `.replaceWith`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#bt1").click
    (
        function ()
        {
            $('div.name').text("")
            $("<div>John Francis</div>").appendTo('div.name');
            alert("Your full name is John Francis");
        }
    );

    $("#bt2").click
    (
        function ()
        {  
            $("div.name div").replaceWith("<div>Francis</div>");
            alert("Your nickname is Francis");
        }
    );
});
```